# Capturing first frame takes up to 1 second

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi4

I am running a simple python program using OpenCV on a Raspberry Pi 4.
The problem is that when taking the first frame it takes up to 1 second, which seems very strange to me.
The forms that I used were the following and in both, I had the same result.

```
camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
_, img = camera.read()
```

The other option is:

```
camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_V4L2)
_, img = camera.read()
```

I am using a USB camera.

Comment: yes, it takes a moment to initialize the camera and set up the driver. **do not** repeatedly open and close a camera device, unless you have time to waste. it's a heavy object, not a throw-away.

Comment: So starting the camera, druver access etc. takes a long time. Maybe you can find a camera with faster initialization time, or you just start the camera once and keep it running until you need it.